# Parsing urls in .Net (ASP.Net MVC) to figure out what host they are for

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url

I'm trying to add validation to our redirects to prevent us allowing redirections out of the domain.  The urls I need to pass aren't trusted since they could come from the user via the url so I'm wondering what's a good way to parse the url to figure out the host?

I knocked up an initial implementation using Uri.Parse but that doesn't like relative paths.  Most of the legitimate redirects will be just that, and should fairly obviously be allowed.

Here's a snippet of what I've done in my action filter,

```
        bool validRedirection = true;
        RedirectResult redirect = filterContext.Result as RedirectResult;
        if (redirect != null)
        {
            validRedirection = false;
            try
            {
                Uri redirectUri = new Uri(redirect.Url);
                Uri sourceUri = filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.Url;
                if (redirectUri.Host == sourceUri.Host)
                    validRedirection = true;
```

The problem is that if I have /Home/About as the redirect.Url then the Uri throws a UriFormatException.  It would also throw one of those exceptions for http:///www.dilbert.com too (because of the three slashses) but I don't want to let that through.

Is there a more suitable class or an easy way to determine if I have a relative url?  I'm half inclined to use a regex to check for https?:// on the front but given all the ways that hackers seem to be able to subvert url's I'm worried I'll miss a hole.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that if the URL is relative, you can safely assmue that the domains are the same, so check for a leading forward slash, and if it's there, return true before even trying to construct the URI.

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution would be to check to see if `redirect.Url` starts with `/` and not even bother with parsing the URI if it does.

Try something like this:

```
Boolean isValidRedirect()
{
    RedirectResult redirect = filterContext.Result as RedirectResult;

    if (redirect == null)
        return false;

    if (redirect.Url.StartsWith("/"))
        return true;

    Uri redirectUri = new Uri(redirect.Url);
    Uri sourceUri = filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.Url;

    return redirectUri.Host == sourceUri.Host;
}
```